# Make tkinter.Entry readonly but not grayed out

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I like the look of a default tkinter entry-widget, but I want make it read-only without being grayed out.

```py
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
entry1_var = tk.StringVar(root, value='Entry1')
entry1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=entry1_var)
entry1.configure(state='disabled')
#entry1.configure(background="white") does nothing
entry1.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

Can I change the styling of a Entry or should I try making a Label look like a default Entry?

**EDIT**

Also, is it possible to keep the text of the Entry selectable while being read-only/disabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a special option for the background and foreground when the entry is disabled: `disabledbackground` and `disabledforeground`. So to make the disabled entry look more like a regular entry, you can use:

```
entry1.configure(disabledbackground="white", disabledforeground="black")
```

---

To still be able to select the text, you could use a different strategy. Instead of setting the state to disabled, use the `validatecommand` to disallow all edits:

```
import tkinter as tk

def validate():
    return False

root = tk.Tk()

vcmd = (root.register(validate))

entry1_var = tk.StringVar(root, value='Entry1')
entry1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=entry1_var, validatecommand=vcmd)
entry1.update()
entry1.configure(validate="key")
entry1.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

The only thing to note is that when you force an edit that should not be allowed by the validation, by using `entry1_var.set('text')` for example, the validation gets disabled (this is also why we need the `entry1.update()` to actively set the text before starting the validation). So to change the text, you need to disable the validation, update the text and re-enable the validation like:

```
entry1.configure(validate="none")
entry1_var.set("text")
entry1.configure(validate="key")
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can also bind an event to `break` on all keys. You will still be able to select the text by mouse.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.insert(0,"This is a test")
entry.pack()

def disable_entry(event):
    if event.state == 12 and (event.keysym == 'c' or event.keysym == "a"):
        return
    else:
        return "break"

entry.bind("<Key>", disable_entry)
entry.bind("<Button-2>", disable_entry)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is nice because it's simple, but I think it has some downsides. Using the middel mouse button when text is selected copy-pastes the text (can be fixed by also binding `disable_entry` to `<Button-2>`), and things like Ctrl-A and the arrow keys no longer work.

Comment: Agreed - I have slightly edited it to include `ctrl+c` and `ctrl+a`.